Slack Blocks Formatting not working with Workflows
I have an AWS Lambda code here:
def postToSlack(url, message):

   slack_data = json.dumps({'blocks': message})

   headers = {
       "Content-Type": "application/json",
       "Accept": "application/json",
   }

   r = requests.post(url, headers=headers,  data=slack_data)

Where message is the Slack blocks content, generated using their Block Kit Builder.
Example content:
[{
    "type": "rich_text",
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text_section",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Week N: Coding Puzzle, human generation!\n",
                    "style": {
                        "bold": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "divider"
},
{
    "type": "rich_text",
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text_section",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Write the function that takes three dimensions of a brick: height(a), width(b) and depth(c) and returns true if this brick can fit into a hole with the width(w) and height(h).\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "type": "rich_text",
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "rich_text_preformatted",
            "border": 0,
            "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "\ndoesBrickFit(1, 1, 1, 1, 1) ➞ true\n\ndoesBrickFit(1, 2, 1, 1, 1) ➞ true\n\ndoesBrickFit(1, 2, 2, 1, 1) ➞ false\n",
                    "style": {
                        "code": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]

Workflow is a simple webhook.  data is saved as a variable and used in the send message step.
What is actively posted using the workflow is completely unformatted:

Week N... is not bold
There is no divider
For the code block, the backticks are there, but the code is plain text.

It looks like:
[backtick][backtick][backtick]
code
[backtick][backtick][backtick]

I've also just come across that. It seems like a limitation of Slack workflows. Were you able to get this to work or is the only option to use the Slack API/Apps instead?
